# Disk Defragment has odd disk name

Tags: windows, boot, disk-space

I was using disk defragment on windows 7 and saw disk named

\?Volume{eb...

I only have 1 hard disk rest are partion c,d,e,f then this one. I don't see this one in my computer. I see this one in disk defragment. Then in disk management I see 1 disk and 5 partions. One of them just says 199 mb.

What is this volume thing? I read online saying it system recover but wanted to see what it is?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on Computer, Select Manage, and then look down into Disk Management and you will see your partitions there.

When you run Disk Defragmenter, constrain it to just Drive C: , not all your drives.  That will work for you

Comment: So I see  C,D,E,F and something called 199 mb ntfs. Is that 199 the ?Volume I saw in disk defragment? Or that odd name not showing up in Disk Managemt? Is it something for me to worry about like a virus? Also is there a way to get emails when a response is posted on this forum? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is what you saw in Disk Defragmenter.  It could be a recovery partition. So then that is why I say just point Disk Defrag to your main disk.  Separately check your SE user profile to see if you can get emails. I rely upon notifications

Comment: You said it could be a recovery partion. Could it be something else? Anyway to see what it is?

Comment: Probably - depends on your particular machine, but viruses do not normally create partitions

Comment: Sorry but anyway to find out if it's like a hack or something or just a system bootm Not great at computers but little help can figure things out. I saw email setting in SE changed it to 3 hrs see what that does. How do you do notifications? I use this on my mobile so do you have to be on computer and or leave site open?

Comment: Look in the descriptions of the volume in Disk Management. It should tell you. The other questions, you must ask support. Otherwise it will confuse the issue here.

Comment: @Vick - It absolutely is not a virus or a hack.

Comment: 199 MB Healthy (System) its green bar like rest of the partions. But it has cross hatching rest of the partions dont. So I should assume this is the odd named partion in disk defragment and this is the system boot and leave it alone? Or that odd volume is not this 199 mb system boot and if so what is it?

Comment: The cross hatching is a system disk so no problem with it. Just ignore it when defragging

Comment: Based on your reply the odd named partion in disk defragment is this 199 system disk that is cross hatched so just ignore it. If you say correct I am set? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a system partition, so you can safely ignore when defragging

Comment: Thank you! Great to find this site as computer resource..

Answer (score 0):

> **Unique Volume Names**
>
> Two factors can make it hard to reliably mount a specific volume at a
>   specified volume mount point across operating system restarts. One
>   factor is that two different volumes can have the same label, which
>   makes them indistinguishable except by drive letter. The other factor
>   is that drive letters do not necessarily remain the same. If a
>   computer's administrator does not use the Disk Administrator to
>   enforce drive letters, then drive letters can change as drives are
>   removed from or added to the system.
>
> To solve this problem, the system refers to volumes to be mounted with
>   unique volume names. These are strings of this form:
>
> ```
> "\\?\Volume{GUID}\"
> ```

This page has been updated see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-volume

PS this is what a GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) looks like `{D0445962-38B9-421B-B29D-3D440D4E04B5}`, which is a text representation of a 128 bit number.

On this page is a script for making them - https://pastebin.com/QNAAMDNu.

If you make one on your computer you are pretty much guaranteed no one else will generate that particular number for a billion years or so (the earth gets swallowed by the sun before then). The advantage of this is that there is no central registry of GUIDs needed, so they are cheap. Contrast this to network cards that also have a unique number but the manufacturer has to buy numbers from a industry body.